# summernote wysiwyg does not return textarea value

Tags: php, laravel, wysiwyg, summernote

I'm using `laravel` for my webproject. I have the `summernote wysiwyg editor`. 
Now I'm trying to read the value of it. Here is my piece of code:

```
{{Form::open(array('url'=>'admin/info/opvoedingsproject/edit'))}}
<input type="text" name="title" >
<textarea name="description" id="description" class="form-control"></textarea>
<br />
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-green">Bewaar</button>
{{Form::close()}}
```

I get the value of the title input but not of the textarea. This is what I get from `Input::all()`

```
array(4) { ["_token"]=> string(40) "YRDSqwzZrxvs2DvU1AiuGlDDHkobhIWLaYbnUlOo" ["title"]=> string(10) "test title" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["files"]=> string(0) "" }
```

Any help ?

Thanks !

Comment: Apparently, from this [example](https://gist.github.com/soomtong/6635053), you need to fill the `textarea`

Comment: @Razor, Even when I fill the text area it does not work;

Comment: can you share the whole code for the form please? I tested your code (last version of `summernote`) and it works perfectly for me (without filling the textarea).

Comment: This issued has been closed in their github issue https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/74 check it out